# Error: Cannot find module "src/auth/guards/jwt-auth.guard.ts" despite nothing even looking for it

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs, passport.js

I'm seeing the mentioned error, with stack trace below

Error: Cannot find module 'src/auth/guards/jwt-auth.guard'
Require stack:

```
~/Documents/Code/nestjs-passport-learning/dist/src/user/user.service.js
~/Documents/Code/nestjs-passport-learning/dist/src/user/user.module.js
~/Documents/Code/nestjs-passport-learning/dist/src/app.module.js
~/Documents/Code/nestjs-passport-learning/dist/src/main.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:939:15)
```

This error makes no sense, though, as the user module/service is not looking for that auth file at all. It was at one time, but I removed it while trying to debug the error. It seems like something internal to node itself is bugged and still looking at an outdated version of the code.

What happened:

1. Code was working/running perfectly
2. I decided to add "UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)" to one of my user.service methods
3. At the same time I decided to setup debugging, so I added a launch.json file
4. Tried running the code. It built, but had a ton of "can't find bla bla" errors at runtime.
5. I stopped the app and figured the error was do to me not exporting the class in auth.module and not importing the AuthModule in UserModule(which was true).
6. I fixed that error, and restarted
7. Now getting the error message above
8. I removed the "UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)" and all imports to it and AuthModule import in UserModule, as well as the launch.json file(ie revert back to exactly the code that was running perfectly 10 minutes earlier)
9. Still getting the same error(despite there being nothing in the user module that looks for it.

Why is user.service.ts still looking for that jwt-auth.guard.ts file?

Other things I've tried:

- removing the "jwt-auth-guard.ts" file itself
- checking out an earlier version of the code where "jwt-auth-guard.ts" hadn't even been written yet
- restarting my machine

Nothing worked, no matter what, I get that same error, despite the code not being any different the code that worked.

[link to github repo](https://github.com/richard12511/nestjs-passport-learning)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have no idea what's going on, and no idea what to google to even try to fix this problem.

Comment: I get a feeling that this has something to do with circular dependency issue. Do take a look on nestjs ciruclar dependency errors. I'll see what I can do

Comment: The code is running fine for me.

Comment: I think you may be right about the circular dependency issue. The way I initally set it up, UserModule imports AuthModule, and AuthModule imports UserModule. What's weird is that I still can't build, despite reverting the code back to what it was when it worked. It's like VS code or Node is building from some kind of cache, and not what's actually there. You saying it builds for you makes me more convinced of that. Question is, how do I make it build what's there?

Comment: did you try deleting node_modules and package-lock.json together and then run ```npm install```?. This should, hopefully, fix the issue.

Comment: I have run into the same issue after updating nestjs and all its dependencies. Prior to this, my app had been running fine for years

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so after some fiddling in my application, I tried renaming my 'dist' folder to try it, and it worked!  So I guess the "caching" was due to the dist folder.

Peace and happy coding!